# Gradle Plugin: Task C should run if Task A or Task B:

Tags: gradle, build.gradle, gradle-plugin

I am creating Custom Plugin tasks and got into a situation where I need some help.
I create 3 tasks. Task A, B, C in gradle.
Task C should get executed only if A or B got success.
Note that A and B are 2 separate tasks and are not related.

```
class A extends DefaultTask { }

class B extends DefaultTask { }

class C extends DefaultTask { }
```

If I try `C.dependsOn(A); C.dependsOn(B);`, then I think C is dependent on both A **and** B (not A **or** B). Is there any way to specify A **or** B condition here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Gradle offers four methods (and related containers) for task dependencies and ordering:

Style: `t1.<method>(t2)`

1. `dependsOn` - Ensures, that `t2` is executed **if** and **before** `t1` is executed.
2. `finalizedBy` - Ensures, that `t2` is executed **if** and **after** `t2` is executed.
3. `mustRunAfter` - Ensures, that **if both** `t2` and `t1` are executed (caused by other triggers), `t1` is executed **after** `t2`.
4. `shouldRunAfter` - Basically the same as `mustRunAfter`, but may be ignored for special cases (check [the docs](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/more_about_tasks.html#sec:ordering_tasks)).

Your requirement is special and won't be solved by a simple method like above. If I understand your question right, you want to ensure that task C gets executed after tasks A and B, but only if it will be executed anyhow (and not trigger it automatically). You can use `mustRunAfter` for this first part of the requirement. However, you also want to ensure that either task A **or** task B was executed before. I suggest to use the `onlyIf` method to skip task execution for task C, if neither A or B were executed before. Example:

```
task A { }
task B { }

task C {
    mustRunAfter A, B
    onlyIf { A.state.executed || B.state.executed }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add multiple dependencies.

```
task B << {
    println 'Hello from B'
}

task C << {
    println 'Hello from C'
}

task D(dependsOn: ['B', 'C'] << {
    println 'Hello from D'
}
```

The output is:

```
> gradle -q D
Hello from B
Hello from C
Hello from D
```

Comment: Hi Gabriele, Thanks for your reply.  I just want to ensure that Task B or C (in your example ) is already completed before executing D. I don't want D to execute B or C. Any suggestions ?

Comment: @SIVA_J just read better your question. I don't know how to realize the or condition. May be you can try the finalizedBy method but it is not enough to have the or condition.

Comment: from my understanding b.finalizedBy(d) or c.finalizedBy(d) will trigger task D after b , c task execution. However I don't want D to be triggered automatically. I just want to ensure if B or C (any one) is completed before D is executed. I am still exploring on dynamic tasks

Answer (score 0):

I think the answer to the PM question in gradle 7.x+ would be something like:

```
A.finalizedBy('C')
B.finalizedBy('C')

tasks.register('C'){
  onlyIf{
    (gradle.taskGraph.hasTask('A') &&
            tasks.A.getState().getExecuted() &&
            tasks.A.getState().getFailure() == null) 
     ||
    (gradle.taskGraph.hasTask('B') &&
                    tasks.B.getState().getExecuted() &&
                    tasks.B.getState().getFailure() == null)
        
  }
}
```

With this condition you can't execute C by itself as in 'gradle C'.

Another option could be a Task listener:

```
A.finalizedBy('C')
B.finalizedBy('C')

gradle.taskGraph.afterTask { Task task, TaskState taskState ->
    if (['A','B'].contains(task.getName())){
        if(taskState.getFailure() == null){
            project.tasks.getByName('C').setEnabled(true)
        }else{
            project.tasks.getByName('C').setEnabled(false)
        }
    }
}
```

With this option it is possible to just execute C with 'gradle C'.

Yes another option could be to declare inputs to C and then in a task listener change C's input as necessary to influence its upToDate check.

Then A and B are executed directly or by some other trigger. if both A and B are in the tasks graph then C will probably be executed twice. if A and B are executed in parallel the result IMO is unpredictable.